# Need help with the phrasal verb "be through" and some prepositions

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I was wondering if the the sentence below is grammatically correct especially the way the phrasal verb "be through" was used?

> Now that we are through on our discussion with nouns and verbs, let us continue on your activities.

I was trying to correct/ rephrase it like this:

> Now that we are through with our discussion on nouns and verbs, let us continue on your activities.

Comment: _Through with_ is certainly better than  the first sentence. But to me it is problematic in that it is more informal than the rest of the phrasing, and also that it has an implication that the activity that has been completed was difficult or troublesome.

Comment: @ColinFine thanks for pointing that out. I think I should replace "through" with "finish" to make it more clear and remove the difficulty the first sentence tries to imply.

Comment: _Now that we have finished our discussion..._ is fine.

Comment: Also "continue on your activities" isn't normal. Either just "continue your activities" or "continue with your activities" would be better.